# Some Gnome3 workspace management actions missing on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, workspaces

I use Ubuntu with the Gnome3 shell. Right-clicking a window title provides a number of useful actions for managing the association between windows and workspaces. Up to Ubuntu 15.04, these actions included `move to workspace N`  and `only on this workspace`. After the upgrade, these actions are no longer on the right-click menu.  Is there anything I can do to restore them, either via GSettings or using an extension?

Comment: In Gnome3 shell on 15.04, right clicking window title bar gives me the option to `Move to Workspace Down` no  selection for `Workspace N`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Prior to 15.04, it would give you that option, as well as move to workspace up/down.

Comment: Do you have gnome-tweak-tool installed?  If not, you may want to install this tool to assist in controlling appearance and behavior.  From Terminal `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`.  It has a section for controlling workspaces.  And, there are many extensions which can be added to improve the look and feel of Gnome-shell.

Comment: I've already looked in tweak-tool, and it doesn't have any options for this change. I do use Gnome shell extensions, and indeed I asked in the original question if there are extensions that fix this change. I've already looked at extensions.gnome.org, but nothing obvious leaps out.

Comment: Try enabling your workspaces as static and choose 4 as the number of workspaces.

Comment: One additional possibility.  In your keyboard shortcuts, select Navigation and try to enable a `Workspace down` shortcut.

Comment: I don't see how making the workspaces static helps. However, the suggestion to use keyboard accelerators is a good one. I already have a `move to workspace up/down` action on the context menu, but by `assigning move to workspace N` keyboard accelerators that does solve half of my issue.

Comment: I have this same problem. I just upgraded to 15.04 and I lost the context menu ability (available from right clicking on every application's title bar) to move an application to a specific workspace. I only have Move to Workspace Up and/or Move to Workspace Down, where I used to also have Move to Workspace n where n was on of the desktops I currently had statically defined. The keyboard shortcut kind of helps, but I would like the old functionality. Where can I turn this on or configure it as an option?

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution, [suggested by RCF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625190/some-gnome3-workspace-management-actions-missing-on-ubuntu-15-04#comment887699_625190), is to set keyboard accelerators (shortcuts) from the settings dialog for `move to workspace 1/2/3/4`